How did General Wing know where to drill for Golgotha?
A significant portion of Cryptonomicon revolves around a race between multiple parties to find the coordinates of a massive cache of gold buried during WW2. One of those parties is General Wing, a Chinese military commander who helped to bury the gold. For most of the novel, he does not know the precise whereabouts of the cache, even going to far as to framing the protagonist, Randy Waterhouse, and trying to use Van Eck phreaking to get Randy to divulge the precise coordinates.
At the end of the novel, General Wing has begun tunneling towards Golgotha, the gold cache. It seems unlikely that he would waste resources tunneling in the general direction of Golgotha, so while it is not explicitly stated that he now is aware of the precise location, the implication is there. By the end of the novel, did Wing learn the precise coordinates of Golgotha, and if so, how did he learn those coordinates?

Wing remembered the approximate area and, through intermediaries, gradually bought land near the site of the gold cache.  The cache location was dubbed Golgotha by Goto Dengo, the japanese mine engineer who designed the site.
Wing learned the latitude and longitude by Van Eyck phreaking Randy Waterhouse's laptop while he (Randy) was in the jail cell next to Enoch Root.
Randy caused his laptop to display the wrong lat/long so Wing could not beat him to the site, but it couldn't be too far off the true location or Wing would have seen through the ruse and not let Randy get out of jail.
The book doesn't say this, but I believe Wing made use of satellite and air surveillance to find the distinctive triple-hilltop and small lake of the real site.  That's how he knew where to tunnel in the final days of the story.  Randy's false coordinates delayed Wing long enough for Randy to get out of jail, return covertly to the Philippines, and, with his business partner Avi and Goto Dengo, organize his own operation to recover the gold.

Also, towards the end, he would presumably have had some information on where Randy and co were actually searching as there is reference to various local groups following Wing's orders to blockade them in to try and prevent personnel/equipment movements.
